# $(I:a)=I\Rightarrow a\in A^{\times}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit, $I\subset A$ a non-zero ideal and $a\in A$. I'm trying to prove or disprove that if $(I:a)=I$, then $a\in A^{\times}$.

I feel that this is false, but I find it very hard to give a counter example. If it's false in deed, I wonder what additional hypothesis would make it true.

Comment: If $I$ is prime, and $a\in A\setminus I$ then $(I:a)=I$. So not that hard to find a counterexample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested, this statement is false in general. A quick and dirty counterexample is: let $A$ be a non-zero ring, $I=A$, and $a=0\in A$. Then $(I:a)=(A:0)=A=I,$ but of course $a=0\notin A^\times$.

And a less trivial counterexample is: $A=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}, I=2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$, and $a=\bar{3}$ (the image of $3$ under the natural surjection $\mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}.$ Now $(I:a)=(2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}:\bar{3})=2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}=I,$ but $\bar{3}$ is not a unit as it is a zero-divisor in $A$.